# RODBC & foreach

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, rodbc

I would like to use a foreach syntax for querying a locally stored database.

My code looks like that:

```
h <- odbcDriverConnect(connection)

cl<-makeCluster(no_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach(i = 1:dim(Table)[1], 
        .combine = rbind,
        .export = "h",
        .packages = "RODBC")  %dopar%  {
          cat(i,"\n")
          #h <- odbcDriverConnect(connection)
          sqlQuery(query)
        }

odbcCloseAll()
stopCluster(cl)
```

When I use %do% instead of %dopar% it works properly, but when I try to make it a parallel I get this error:

> Error in { :    task 1 failed - "first argument is not an open RODBC
>   channel" In addition: Warning message: In e$fun(obj, substitute(ex),
>   parent.frame(), e$data) :   already exporting variable(s): h

When I place h inside the foreach loop it works, however I understand that create connection on every single step and I would like to avoid that. Is there any way I could export that connection to foreach (the same way it is made with other variables)?

Comment: *I would like to use a foreach syntax for quering a locally stored database*...why? What is your true problem? Or are you doing this to learn?

Comment: I just need to get results of some querries that aren't related to each other so I expect that is quite parallel problem. I hope that that way I can get results faster. Am I wrong?

However even if it does not make it faster I would like to know if it is possible to export connection istead of variable in foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't export database connections to the workers because they can't be properly serialized and deserialized (since they contain things like socket connections). Instead, you need to create them on the workers, but for efficiency, you should create them once and then use them repeatedly from your foreach loops.

Since you're using `doParallel`, you can initialize the workers with `clusterEvalQ`:

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  library(RODBC)
  connection <- "???"  # how are you setting this?
  h <- odbcDriverConnect(connection)
})
```

You can then use `h` from your foreach loops as long as you prevent foreach from auto-exporting `h` to the workers:

```
foreach(i = 1:dim(Table)[1],
        .combine = rbind,
        .noexport = "h",  # make sure h is *not* exported!
        .packages = "RODBC")  %dopar%  {
  cat(i, "\n")
  sqlQuery(h, query)
}
```

It's important to use `.noexport="h"`, otherwise the good `h` will be masked and you'll get an error from RODBC.

Comment: Thanks it's working! One more question - do I need to have free RAM for every instance of ODBC connection? It work much faster for smaller database, but when I try to connect to bigger one I the CPUs start to be idle after couple minutes and I think that maybe its connected with lack of RAM.

Comment: @Swistak Sorry, I don't know very much about databases or ODBC in particular. I suggest that you try running a process monitoring tool (task manager?) on your computer to see if the R sessions are using a lot of memory.

Comment: @Stave Thanks, I tried it, unfortunatelly RAM taken by ODBC connection isn't shown in task manager as part of R or even another process (however I can see that ram usage significantly drop when I close the connection). Once again thanks for help with foreach package!