# Can I Use Only One RODBC Connection in Foreach using doParallel in R?

Tags: r, sql-server, foreach, rodbc, doparallel

I know that I can open an SQL Server connection in each worker, however, it opens multiple connections to the server at the same time. My work's Database Administrators are saying that I am using too many system resources by having multiple connections open at the same time, and that I need to use only one connection. Is it possible to open a single connection and pass it to each worker? I did read the answer as to why this can't be performed here: [RODBC & foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960725/rodbc-foreach), but I was hoping there may be a new solution or new insights.

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
clusterEvalQ(cl, {
    library(RODBC)
    Conn   <- odbcConnect("SERVER_NAME")
})

foreach(iter=1:10, .noexport="Conn") %dopar% {
    # Code block
}
```

I also need this because I am creating a temporary table and need each worker to be able to access the connection that has the temporary table. Otherwise, each worker opens a new connection and doesn't have access to the connection with the temporary table. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to work concurrently over a single connection, even if you could share it.

If you want multiple child processes, each with their own connection, to see the same data, then either use a permanent table, or a global temporary table created in the driver process.  eg

```
create table ##foo(...)
```

> Global temporary tables are automatically dropped when the session
>   that created the table ends and all other tasks have stopped
>   referencing them. The association between a task and a table is
>   maintained only for the life of a single Transact-SQL statement. This
>   means that a global temporary table is dropped at the completion of
>   the last Transact-SQL statement that was actively referencing the
>   table when the creating session ended.

[CREATE TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)